# How to read data from a NON secured webpage in java(Router or AP)?

Tags: java, html, httprequest

Here is my code to get the source from the access point I was trying to poll:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://x.x.x.x"); //Some valid IP
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        System.out.println("In");
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Here is what I got instead of the desired source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/x
html1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_canopy.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_canopypda.css" media="handheld" />

<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=index.htm?mac_esn=0a003e40eb1e' />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=
no' />
<title>Welcome to Canopy</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--- Hide script from old browsers
function CheckForJS()
{
  var d = new Date();
  var t = d.getTime();
  document.cookie = "JS=true; expires=" + (t+600);
}
// end hiding from old browsers -->
</script>

</head>

<body onload="CheckForJS();">
<p>
Press <a href="http:index.htm?mac_esn=0a003e40eb1e">Here</a> to Continue.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to access the web gui for this unit to grab its signal strength and store it in a text file. I kind of think the problem is that the gui is not secured by https standards and requires more authorization but it could just be that I am doing the process wrong to begin with. If anyone can help me get the full source of the page or steer me in the right direction of what I need to do, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag

```
<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=index.htm?mac_esn=0a003e40eb1e' />
```

means that a web browser would refresh the page with url `index.htm?mac_esn=0a003e40eb1e` after 0 seconds, i.e. redirect to that page.

You need to do the same, i.e. parse that line and do another request.